# Add unique ID to containing div of file input thumbnail image

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have thumbnail previews of a users selected images prior to upload. It will also allow a user to re-arrange the order of the images using jQuery UI. I want to track the order of the images by adding a unique ID to each thumbnails containing div, but I am not able to generate a unique ID. See Code below. Ideally I would like the div ID to match the image name, so then after the form post I use it to match to the filename in the `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`. For example, if the uploaded image is called `pic1.jpg`, the `div` containing the thumbnail would be `<div id = "pic1">`. The line in question would seem to be `div.id = File.name`, but I am unable to generate a unique ID of any kind?

**CODE**

```
//jQuery UI sort
$(function () {
  $("#upload-thumbnails").sortable();
  $("#upload-thumbnails").disableSelection();
});
//Thumbnail preview
jQuery(function ($) {
  var filesInput = document.getElementById("ImageUploads");

  filesInput.addEventListener("change", function (event) {

var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
var output = document.getElementById("upload-thumbnails");

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  var file = files[i];

  var picReader = new FileReader();

  picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {

    var picFile = event.target;

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = File.name;
    div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
      "title='" + picFile.name + "'/><a href='#' class='remove_pict'>Remove</a>";

    output.insertBefore(div, null);
    div.children[1].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
      div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    });

  });

  //Read the image
  picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

});
});

Comment: Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases while we uploading images we rename them as the time stamp because of the uniqueness. But for searching, dealing with time stamp is much harder, then add a class name of the div as the file name.

```
...
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = Date.now();
div.className += ' ' + File.name;
...
```

I am sure this will be help full.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get the question :)

Try instead:

```
$(div).attr('id', 'yourIDHere')
```

Or you never use your defined var file , could it not be?

```
div.id = file.name;
```

You can generate UUIDs via JS see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)

Comment: Basically I need to add a unique ID to the div that contains the thumbnail, but it needs to be some value so that I can match it to the actual file when I post the form.